# Why unidirectional @OneToMany update is not working

Tags: java, jdbc, eclipselink, jpa-2.1, java-ee-8

I am completely new to JPA and ORM concept, so I am hoping someone can lucidly explain what might be the problem with my code.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "PERSISTENCE_customer")

public class Customer implements Serializable {
    
     private static final long serialVersionUID = 1005220876458L;
     @Id
     @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
     private Long id;
     private String firstName;
     private String lastName;
     @OneToMany (cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
     private List<CustomerOrder> orders;
}
@Entity
@Table(name = "PERSISTENCE_ORDER")
public class CustomerOrder implements Serializable{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 199102142021L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    @NotNull
    String status;
    @NotNull
    @OneToMany (cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<LineItem> lineItems = new ArrayList();
    @NotNull
    private String orderNumber;
    ................
    ................
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "PERSISTENCE_LINEITEM")
public class LineItem implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1991217202100959L;
     @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    @NotNull
    private Integer quantity;
    @NotNull
    private Part part;
}
```

Initially, the Customer entity is created through the user interface and persisted successfully. Later, the customer has an order and I update the Customer with CustomerOrder as follow:

```
private void UpdateCustomer(Customer customer) {
        FacesContext fc = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        List<ShoppingCartItem> shoppingCart = getShoppingCart();
        CustomerOrder order = new CustomerOrder();
        List<CustomerOrder> orders = customer.getOrders();
        order.setLastUpdated(new Date());
        order.setOrderNumber(getInvoiceNumber());
        List<LineItem> lineItems = shoppingCart
                .stream()
                .map(e -> (new LineItem(e.getPart(), e.getQuantity())))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
        order.setLineItems(lineItems);
        order.setStatus("Pending Shipment");
        order.setTotal(getTotal());
        orders.add(order);
        customer.setOrders(orders);
        try {
            updateOrders(customer, orders);
            fc.addMessage(null,
                    new FacesMessage("Customer order added successfuly"));
        } catch (ListServiceException e) {
            FacesMessage errMsg = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_FATAL,
                    "Error while adding customer order: ", e.getMessage());
            fc.addMessage(null, errMsg);
        }
    }
private void updateOrders(Customer cust, List<CustomerOrder> orders) throws ListServiceException {
            
        try { //em is the EntityManager injected as the field member
            if (em != null) {
                if (em.isOpen()) {
                    Customer c = getCustomer(cust.getId());
                    c.setOrders(orders);
                    em.merge(c);
                 } else {
                    logger.severe("Entity manager is closed");
            }
            else {
                logger.severe("Entity manager is NULL");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw ThrowListServiceException.wrapException(e);
        }
    }
```

Once the EntityManage merges I get the following exception. I was under the impression that I don't need to explicitly persist the LineItem and CustomerOrder entities myself. I thought that the JPA will persist all the entities in the object graph. Why am I getting this exception? (I am using GlassFish 5.1 server with EclipseLink JPA)

Thanks in advance.

```
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Column 'ORDERS_ID'  cannot accept a NULL value.
Error Code: 30000
Call: INSERT INTO PERSISTENCE_CUSTOMER_PERSISTENCE_ORDER (orders_ID, Customer_ID) VALUES (?, ?)
    bind => [2 parameters bound]
Query: DataModifyQuery(name="orders" sql="INSERT INTO PERSISTENCE_USER_PERSISTENCE_ORDER (orders_ID, User_ID) VALUES (?, ?)")
    at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException.sqlException(DatabaseException.java:331)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.executeDirectNoSelect(DatabaseAccessor.java:905)
 ...............................
.................................
Caused by: java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Column 'ORDERS_ID'  cannot accept a NULL value.
```

## Update

Using the IDE (Netbeans) debugger, I stepped through the code, and as I predicted, during the entity merge the JPA does not add new entities that are part of the object graph to the persistence context. For instance, in the updateOrders() method when I try to update the existing Customer object with a list of new CustomerOrder object, the JPA doesn't figure out that the elements in the List are not part of the persistence context yet and they need to be added. As a result, I had to modify my code to first add the List to the persistence context and then merge the Customer object with the newly persisted List. By doing so I no longer get the exception.

By the way, at moment, all the mapping relationships are unidirectional because I didn't see any reasons to use bidirectional mapping. However, would I gain anything by making these mappings bidirectionals?

Comment: When exactly do you get the error. When you run the project?Can you explain them a little more?Thank you.

Comment: Hi Yusuf. Good question. When I step through the code using the debugger, I see that updateOrders() method completes without any error or exception. I even go a step further and retrieve the Customer right after it is merged in updateOrders() and the object graph looks good and accurate. The exception occurs somewhere in the JSF rendering phase when it uses the Customer object to populate the UI page but debugger can't show that process.

Comment: Thank you for good explain. I suppose this has nothing to do with @onetomany.You did use to true.The exception you added is giving a null error.I keep checking the code

Answer (score 0):

Your OneToMany mapping is missing join specification or mappedBy value

Comment: Sir3nka, according to the JPA spec, the unidirectional mapping does not require mappedBy, nor a JointColumn, though JoinColum eliminates the need of using an extra join table. Could it be that when I update an existing Customer object with a new CustomerOrder that is not part of the persistence context yet be the problem? When persisting a new entity, the JPA will persist the entire entity graph, however, from the exception, it seems this is not the case when merging an entity. I feel the JPA expects me to persist the CustomerORder first the merge it with Customer. Is this correct?

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that.
Firstly You should commit new order to database.Then you should link it with user.I'm not sure if this solves your problem but this is a problem.Can you check it ?

Comment: Yusuf, as I indicated earlier. I thought about the problem and I solved the it

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, if you keep customer information in your Order entity, it may solve this problem.

```
@ManyToOne ()
    private Customer customer;
```

And in your Customer entity you should put **mappedBy=customer** for orders field.

After that, instead of giving orders for customer, you can give customer for a specific order. In my opinion it will achieve a better relationship mapping;

```
order.setCustomer(customer);
```

I hope i understood it right and this will solve your problem. When you give customer detail for order, you **dont** need to give orderlist detail for the same customer. Only one of them should be enough.

Comment: Erdem, thanks for the comment but I already solve the problem. See the update to the question. The problem was my understanding of how JPA operates when merging objects. I thought if a new entity (i.e. CustomerOrder) is added to an existing Customer entity, the JPA is smart enough to figure out that the new entity (CustomerOrder) is not part of the persistence context yet and it needs to first persist this new entity before merging it with the Customer entity. By manually adding the CustomerOrder and then merging it with the Customer, the problem was solved.

Comment: Erdem, also what you are suggesting is a design decision, which is valid, and perhaps another solution to the problem domain.

Comment: Hey Tony. I'm glad that you solved the problem by adding Order manually.  But creating a new list for orders and updating the whole OrdersList manually sounded a little bit painful for me.  If you keep Customer Information for each order, it will inflate the list for you automatically and you won't need to deal with the customer's whole OrderList all the time if you ask me. :). Well, I would prefer dealing with one order instead of the whole list all the time.

Comment: Erdem: More I think about your design suggestion the more I like it and I might go that way, however, at the moment, I am struggling with unidirectional and bidirectional mapping concepts, and I really don't know when to use one or the other. I also like to use of @JointColumn to eliminate the mapping table but I can't make it working, so once I get a better handle on JAP, I will make design changes. Thanks again

Comment: With bidirectional mapping, you can access both directions. For example, you have a customer who is retrieved from a repository. If customer and order have a correct bidirectional relationship, you can get customers to order just using getter (customer.getOrders). Also if you have a ticket and you can access the customer of the ticket by getter ticket.getCustomer. It provides many useful skills like that.

Comment: And if this answer helped you event little bit, could you upwote please? Thank you :)

Comment: You can click up the arrow of the answer

Comment: Erdem, did you get the upVote?

Comment: No i didnt. You should Click up arrow near the title of answer then it will turn to green.

Comment: I did click the up arrow, so I am not sure why?

Comment: Erdem, if you want, complete your answer with an example, and I will accept the answer with a green check-mark rather than just an upvote.